# Convert a string to regular expression ruby

Tags: ruby, regex, string, ruby-1.9.3

I need to convert string like "/[\w\s]+/" to regular expression.

```
"/[\w\s]+/" => /[\w\s]+/
```

I tried using different `Regexp` methods like:

`Regexp.new("/[\w\s]+/") => /\/[w ]+\//`, similarly `Regexp.compile` and `Regexp.escape`. But none of them returns as I expected.

Further more I tried removing backslashes:

`Regexp.new("[\w\s]+") => /[w ]+/` But not have a luck.

Then I tried to do it simple:

```
str = "[\w\s]+"
=> "[w ]+"
```

It escapes. Now how could string remains as it is and convert to a regexp object?

Answer (score 182, accepted):

Looks like here you need the initial string to be in single quotes (refer [this page](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Strings#Single_quotes))

```
>> str = '[\w\s]+'
 => "[\\w\\s]+" 
>> Regexp.new str
 => /[\w\s]+/
```

Comment: or you use 2 backslashes "[\\w\\s]+"

Answer (score 151):

To be clear

```
  /#{Regexp.quote(your_string_variable)}/
```

is working too

**edit:** wrapped your_string_variable in Regexp.quote, for correctness.

Comment: Just found out that you _can't_ append options that way, like `/#{your_regex}/#{options}`.

Comment: I suppose that you're talking about Rails? `options` is a Hash, and Ruby is not soooo dynamic =)

Comment: This doesn't do what OP is asking on Ruby 2.1, it converts "[\w\s]+" => /[w ]+/

Comment: Please note that answer was given in 2012 year :) At that time everything was perfect

Comment: It was a perfect year.

Comment: Combining the answers can avoid string interpolation: Regexp.new(Regexp.quote(your_string_variable))

Answer (score 38):

This method will safely escape all characters with special meaning:

```
/#{Regexp.quote(your_string)}/
```

For example, `.` will be escaped, since it's otherwise interpreted as 'any character'.

*Remember to use a single-quoted string unless you want regular string interpolation to kick in, where backslash has a special meaning.*

Comment: Nice because it explains how we can protect the string variable that may contain signs (such as `+.`) that would be interpreted in the Regexp.

Comment: This doesn't do what OP is asking on Ruby 2.1, it converts "[\w\s]+" => /\[w\ \]\+/

Comment: @LucaSpiller you need to use a single-quoted string, backslash is treated as a special character in double-quoted strings, which is why e.g. `"\n"` is a newline but `'\n'` isn't.

Answer (score 10):

Using % notation:

```
%r{\w+}m => /\w+/m
```

or

```
regex_string = '\W+'
%r[#{regex_string}]
```

From [help](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Literals#The_.25_Notation):

> %r[ ] Interpolated Regexp (flags can appear after the closing
>   delimiter)

Comment: This doesn't do what OP is asking on Ruby 2.1, it converts "[\w\s]+" => /[ws]+/

Comment: @Luca Spiller, thanks, single quotes should be used there, I'll update answer.

Answer (score 6):

The gem [to_regexp](https://github.com/seamusabshere/to_regexp) can do the work.

```
"/[\w\s]+/".to_regexp => /[\w\s]+/
```

You also can use the modifier:

```
'/foo/i'.to_regexp => /foo/i
```

> Finally, you can be more lazy using :detect

```
'foo'.to_regexp(detect: true)     #=> /foo/
'foo\b'.to_regexp(detect: true)   #=> %r{foo\\b}
'/foo\b/'.to_regexp(detect: true) #=> %r{foo\b}
'foo\b/'.to_regexp(detect: true)  #=> %r{foo\\b/}
```

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this, where I literally need to change the string '/[\w\s]+/' to a regex in a transpiler. I used **eval**:

```
irb(main):001:0> eval( '/[\w\s]+/' )
=> /[\w\s]+/
```