# Use ARGV[] argument vector to pass a regular expression in Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex, argv

I am trying to use `gsub` or `sub` on a regex passed through terminal to `ARGV[]`.

Query in terminal: `$ruby script.rb input.json "\[\{\"src\"\:\"`

Input file first 2 lines:

```
[{
    "src":"http://something.com",
    "label":"FOO.jpg","name":"FOO",
    "srcName":"FOO.jpg"
}]
[{
    "src":"http://something123.com",
    "label":"FOO123.jpg",
    "name":"FOO123",
    "srcName":"FOO123.jpg"
}]
```

script.rb:

```
dir = File.dirname(ARGV[0])
output = File.new(dir + "/output_" + Time.now.strftime("%H_%M_%S") + ".json", "w")
open(ARGV[0]).each do |x|
x = x.sub(ARGV[1]),'')
output.puts(x) if !x.nil?
end
output.close
```

This is very basic stuff really, but I am not quite sure on how to do this. I tried:

- `Regexp.escape` with this pattern: `[{"src":"`.
- Escaping the characters and not escaping.
- Wrapping the pattern between quotes and not wrapping.

Comment: I don't understand what your code is supposed to do. Could you explain it, please? It might help to include the input (a JSON file?) and the expected output.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Interpolating a string into a regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/150095/interpolating-a-string-into-a-regex)

Comment: Read "[ask]" and "[mcve]". Show us an example of your call to your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Meditate on this:

I wrote a little script containing:

```
puts ARGV[0].class 
puts ARGV[1].class
```

and saved it to disk, then ran it using:

```
ruby ~/Desktop/tests/test.rb foo /abc/
```

which returned:

```
String
String
```

The documentation says:

> The pattern is typically a Regexp; if given as a String, any regular expression metacharacters it contains will be interpreted literally, e.g. '\d' will match a backlash followed by ‘d’, instead of a digit.

That means that the regular expression, though it *appears* to be a regex, it isn't, it's a string because `ARGV` only can return strings because the command-line can only contain strings.

When we pass a string into `sub`, Ruby recognizes it's not a regular expression, so it treats it as a literal string. Here's the difference in action:

```
'foo'.sub('/o/', '') # => "foo"
'foo'.sub(/o/, '') # => "fo"
```

The first can't find `"/o/"` in `"foo"` so nothing changes. It can find `/o/` though and returns the result after replacing the two "o".

Another way of looking at it is:

```
'foo'.match('/o/') # => nil
'foo'.match(/o/) # => #<MatchData "o">
```

where `match` finds nothing for the string but can find a hit for `/o/`.

And all that leads to what's happening in your code. Because `sub` is being passed a string, it's trying to do a literal match for the regex, and won't be able to find it. You need to change the code to:

```
sub(Regexp.new(ARGV[1]), '')
```

but that's not all that has to change. `Regexp.new(...)` will convert what's passed in into a regular expression, but if you're passing in `'/o/'` the resulting regular expression will be:

```
Regexp.new('/o/') # => /\/o\//
```

which is probably not what you want:

```
'foo'.match(/\/o\//) # => nil
```

Instead you want:

```
Regexp.new('o') # => /o/
'foo'.match(/o/) # => #<MatchData "o">
```

So, besides changing your code, you'll need to make sure that what you pass in is a valid expression, *minus* any leading and trailing `/`.

Comment: Thanks for that, it is really quite detailed.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11647572/794242) in the thread [Convert a string to regular expression ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8652715/convert-a-string-to-regular-expression-ruby), you should use

```
x = x.sub(/#{ARGV[1]}/,'')
```

Comment: Hi, I tried string interpolation. I retried with your example and the following ARGV /\[\{\"src\"\:\"/
\[\{\"src\"\:\"
src
/src/
"src" to no avail. Thanks.

Comment: Are there two regex in that string?  what is `src` and `"src"` for?

Comment: So weird, now I have tried on my Windows machine and it works. Just not on my Mac. I haven't done it any different.

Answer (score 0):

I tested it with this file (test.rb):

```
puts "You should not see any number [0123456789].".gsub(/#{ARGV[0]}/,'')
```

I called the file like so:

```
ruby test.rb "\d+"
# => You should not see any number [].
```